# enabling vue.js support in Pycharm

Tags: javascript, pycharm, vuejs2

I downloaded a plugin from here https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8057-vue-js
and installed it into my old Pycharm 4.5:

[image]

But when I try to create a `.vue` file I am met with misunderstanding:

[image]

Why is this so? Is my Pycharm too old?